# Finding the Palindrome of a List using Prolog :- Exercise 3.5 " Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence" by Ivan Btrako

Tags: prolog

I've been programming with java for the past 3 years, and I have just started learning Prolog. I downloaded SWI-Prolog to run my code on and trace, but I'm having trouble with this particular question.

```
/*concatinates 2 Lists together*/
 conc([],L,L).
 conc([X|T],L2,[X|T1]):-
     conc(T,L2,T1).

/*Finds the reverse a List*/    
reverse([],[]).
reverse([H|T],ReversedList):-
    reverse(T,Reverse),
    conc(Reverse,[H],ReversedList).

palindrome(L):-
    reverse(L,L1),
    L is L1.
```

for example if I enter

```
palindrome([m,a,d,a,m]).
```

L is [m,a,d,a,m] & L1 should be [m,a,d,a,m] returned from the reverse predicate.

`L = L1` and output should be true. However an error is printed that I don't understand

```
ERROR: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[m,a,d,a,m]' (a list) ("x" must hold one character)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] [m,a|...]is[m,a|...]
ERROR:    [8] palindrome([m,a|...]) at c:/users/d/desktop/trial.pl:97
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

My code works only if I change the predicate to:

```
palindrome(L):-
    reverse(L,L).
```

I don't understand why since the logic is the same... `L = L1` is the same as calling L1, L to begin with.

Also, this is the code for the predicate without using the reverse function. I'm having trouble understanding why we have the palidrome1([_]) base case & why if I don't place a bracket around [First] for the conc function, it returns false.

```
palindromel( [] ).
palindromel( [_] ).
palindromel( [First | Rest]) :-
    conc( Middle, [First], Rest), /*Do I have to put First in a list bracket?*/
    palindromel( Middle).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However an error is printed that I don't understand.

The error that is causing the line is

```
L is L1
```

[is/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2) says:

> ```
> -Number is +Expr
>
> True when Number is the value to which Expr evaluates. 
> Typically, is/2 should be used with unbound left operand. 
> If equality is to be tested, =:=/2 should be used.
> ```

Since the left side is not a number and the right side is not an expression  `is/2`  cannot be used.

---

> I don't understand why since the logic is the same.

Actually the logic is not the same. `is/2` is not the same as unification, `=/2`.

The reason

```
palindrome(L):-
    reverse(L,L).
```

works because there is just one variable for both arguments to `reverse/2`. As such the input to `reverse/2` and the result of `reverse/2` must unify. In this case because the input and the output are the same if they are a palindrome, they can be unified.

Another way to see this is with this variation

```
palindrome(L1):-
    reverse(L1,L2),
    L1 = L2.
```

This time I used two different variables for `reverse/2` but then did the unification as a separate step. The first way

```
palindrome(L):-
    reverse(L,L).
```

is the same as this variation but in the first way the unification is factored out by using `reverse(L,L)`.

---

> I'm having trouble understanding why we have the palidrome1([_]) base case.

When I start creating code to solve a problem I work the problem out manually in my head or on paper. I start with the simplest cases and work toward the more complex. For palindromes, the simplest case is a word with no letters.

So if the input is an empty list `[]` the palindrome is an empty list `[]`

```
palindromel( [] ).
```

The next harder case is a word with one letter which would be `[_]`.

```
palindromel( [_] ).
```

The next harder case is a word with two letters which would be `[A,A]`.

```
palindromel( [A,A] ).
```

and so on

```
 palindromel( [A,B,A] ).
 palindromel( [A,B,B,A] ).
 palindromel( [A,B,C,B,A] ).
 palindromel( [A,B,C,C,B,A] ).
```

To avoid having to create an endless list of clauses, recursion is used. However for palindrome the two easy cases become base cases for recursion and the rest are done using the base cases with the recursive clause.

> if I don't place a bracket around [First] for the conc function, it returns false.

The reason I asked about "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence" by Bratko is that in his book he has the students create `conc/3` but doesn't note that it is really [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3). If you are using the book do yourself a favor and use `append/3` instead as it has no bugs and odds are somewhere along `conc/3` will fail while `append/3` will work.

`append/3` appends two list to create a third list. If you don't put `[]` around a single character then it is not a list but a character and `append/3` or `conc/3` will fail.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. Can you also help with the second part of my question? The predicate palindrome1.

Comment: Thanks for the accept vote. You can also give it an up-vote by clicking on the upward pointing triangle by the check.