# Shifting a list N times using Prolog [] issue :- Exercise 3.6 “ Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence” by Ivan Btrako

Tags: list, prolog

I want to create a predicate `shift(List1,List2)` where `List2` is `List1` shifted rotationally by one element to the left.
Example:

```
?- shift([1,2,3,4],L1), shift(L1,L2), shift(L2,L3).
L1 = [2, 3, 4, 1],
L2 = [3, 4, 1, 2],
L3 = [4, 1, 2, 3].
```

I created the predicate

```
conc([],L,L).
conc([X|T],L2,[X|T1]) :-
   conc(T,L2,T1).

shift([H|T],L2) :-
   conc(T,H,L2).
```

However, it's wrong & I don't understand why... It works only if the `H` is surrounded by `[H]`.

```
shift([H|T],L2) :-
   conc(T,[H],L2).
```

The predicate without the `[` `]` only works with 1 shift & it outputs the following:

```
?- shift([1,2,3,4],L1).
L1 = [2, 3, 4|1].
```

Obviously, there's a basic concept I'm confused with, but I can't seem to pin-point what's wrong alone. I'm new at Prolog, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is right in the comment: `conc/3` concatenates lists. When you unify a list with `[H|T]`, you are getting the first _item_ in H and the _remaining list_ in T, but H is not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works only if the H is surrounded by [H]

As I noted [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55022145/1243762), `conc/3` is really the standard predicate [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) which takes in two list and creates a third list.

`append/3` says:

> append(?List1, ?List2, ?List1AndList2)
>   List1AndList2 is the concatenation of List1 and List2

A single term is not a list, e.g. `1` is not a list, but `[1]` is a list.
A list starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

This is the empty list: `[]`

A list can have one item: `[a]`

or more than one item: `[a,b]` and so on. Notice how they always have square brackets.

When you use `conc/3` or `append/3` all three values have to be list, so even if you want to concatenate or append a single item you have to convert it to a list first by surrounding it with `[]` to turn it into a list. So the single item `1` is converted to a list as `[1]`.